# calculate cost from hours worked

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula

I have two columns in my spreadsheet.

```
A                      B
Total Hours Worked     Total Cost
```

`A` is formatted as a duration/time, i.e. `01:34:20` and is the total elapsed time it's taken to complete a task

`B` should be a formula of some sort that calculates the cost. Right now I have the function `A2*25` but this results in `B2` being too little.

What do I need to do to correct the formula so the total cost is correct?

Comment: What is the formula for caculating the total cost? Is it 25 per hour?

Comment: Yeah $25 per hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this as B2 -

```
=(HOUR(A2) + MINUTE(A2) / 60 + SECOND(A2) / 3600)*25
```

Answer (score 2):

Excel stores durations as fractions of days.
You just need to multiply the duration by 24 to have the number of hours worked and you get the correct result.

```
=A2*25*24
```

Comment: Just to add to that, the formula should therefore be `=A2*24*25` which is effectively `(duration)*(hours in the day)*(cost)`

Comment: Thanks. I added it for clarity.